# Что такое Slug size на Heroku?

Tags: heroku

Что такое Slug size?
Ещё на англоязычном стэке я прочитал, что помимо 300 MB есть доступ к "локальной файловой системе", где можно хранить до 1GB. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы закачиваете на хероку ваше веб-приложение, сервер выполняет ряд стандартных задач в зависимости от стека технологий. Это сборка стилей и скриптов, минификация и сжатие файлов и т.д.

В конечном итоге сервер получает собранное и готовое к запуску приложение. Со всеми стилями, скриптами, изображениями и прочими ресурсами. Такое приложение в хероку и называется `slug`.

А `slug size` - это допустимый размер такого приложения. То есть, если ваше приложение в упакованном для запуска виде будет весить больше 300 Мб, хероку его не запустит.

Поэтому обращайте внимание на ресурсы, которые вы храните в репозитории с проектом. Архивы, видео, тяжелую графику - лучше по возможности вообще держать не в репозитории с кодом, а в отдельном хранилище. Например, на [AWS S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3).

---

Доступ к файловой системе хероку может и давать, но для хранения временных файлов - кеша, файлов на аплоаде. В таком хранилище не стоит держать долговременные файлы. Опять-таки - лучше привязать к проекту внешнее хранилище.